# Create a folder on NTFS server using C# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ntfs, unc

I am implementing an application that will create a folder on the NTFS File Server.
For that, I have set up the distributed environment. Meaning, I have machine on which I have hosted my C# Web API and I have NTFS file server on which I have to create folders.

I want my API to create a folder on NTFS machine. How can I do that?
Do I need to share NTFS Drive/Folder to create a subfolder? If so, then with whom I need to share a NTFS folder (**either server user or IIS_USRS**)?

Is there any other way to create a folder without sharing a drive/folder on NTFS folder.

Comment: *All* Windows machines are "NTFS machines". NTFS is the file system used by Windows. You are asking how to create a shared folder. First of all, that's already available through WinRM, Powershell and a lot of other remote management APIs built into Windows. You don't need to create an extra web app for this.

Comment: Why create a shared folder from a web app though? It's far safer to do that during deployment using a script or a policy

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this in the past I have done it through a temporary impersonation.  For example...

```
using (Impersonator impersonate = new Impersonator(@"UserName", "Password", "Domain")) 
{
     //Create directory or copy files across the network
}
```

I believe I lifted my impersonator code from [A small C# Class for impersonating a User](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)

Comment: Thanks @peter.edwards for your response. I have used Impersonation, but I am not able to connect it using my local machine user. I am able to connect it with the other domain user. but I am not able to connect it with my local account.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

if web server and file server are in the same domain, you can consider to use a domain user, and created a shared folder on NTFS server and grant full access for the domain user accessing it. (depends on your requirements).

On web server, for the web application pool, set the domain user as the identity/credential to run the pool. so you can easily use IIS management tool to update it if password gets changed. for the authentication, you can use whatever you want based on requirements, but remember while you call the code to create folders on NTFS server, you need to use app pool user. (for example, if you turn on impersonation on a different user in authentication, in your code, you need to do impersonation using the pool user.)

Case 2,
web server and file server are not in the same domain, I usually will set up a ftp server on the file server to allow specific users to access it (creating folders and upload files....). Otherwise when you may need your IT administrator to make File server domain trust web server domain, then you can do the same thing as case 1.

About impersonation code, it could be something like:

```
    //get the identity of an appPool 
         using(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wid = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
         {
             using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext ImpersonationCtx = wid.Impersonate())
             {
                 //creating folders, uploading files to UNC path... 

                 ImpersonationCtx.Undo();
             }
         }
```

If your case is one of this, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Victor, I am using Impersonation. What I did is, a user from the same domain is able to impersonate but when I am trying to impersonate a local user from my other machine it is not working. Make a note that the user is from an administrative group.

Comment: Hi @AnkitPrajapati, just to ensure, you setup API use impersonation authentication and use API local admin account, but failed to create folders on NTFS machine? If so, did you create the same local account on NTFS machine?

Comment: yes exactly, I did that. I have created a local account on NTFS machine and using that user I am implementing impersonation.

Comment: Usually I setup a ftp server on NTFS machine for the case. Back to your case, did you check the MS KB article 951916, which is about UAC. the policy might reject the access  from a remote machine using local credentials.